# Serializing an ArrayList of Objects with BufferedImages

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedimage

I'm trying to save a game state by serializing a game object that contains an ArrayList of enemies. Each of the items on the ArrayList is an object, and each of those objects contains a BufferedImage to represent the enemy. Java throws an error that the BufferedImages aren't serializable. All the solutions I've found say to just create a new object and fill it with all the data except the images, but I'm not sure how possible that is with the List set up.

```
public void saveGame(){
    GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
    game.enemyList = enemyList;
    game.player = new Player(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    game.player.setScore(player.getScore());
    game.player.setPos(player.getX(), player.getY());

    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("savegame.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(game);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mark the attributes you do not want to serialize as `transient`. V.g., `private transient BufferedImage alienImage;`.

Comment: That should be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the comments so I'll repost it here to close the question.

> Mark the attributes you do not want to serialize as transient. V.g., private transient BufferedImage alienImage;. –  SJuan76